# Can I move a float stored in a _m128 SSE register directly to a normal register?

Tags: sse, cpu-registers

I'm trying to super-optimize some code, and a place that I'd like to speed up is the following.

I'd like to take the answer of a dot-product operation (_mm_dp_ps) which is an _m128, and save the answer directly into a register. However, using _mm_store, this would mean that I'd have to write a full 128 bits to an array, then load the first entry of that array.

Call my _m128 variable "vector".

Can I do float ans = *((float *)&vector)?

If this works the question of whether it even helps remains. Will ans be loaded into a register, or will I have to load it from L1 regardless?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Now... have you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is actually already in register; you simply need to tell the compiler to interpret it as a scalar instead of a vector.  You're looking for the `_mm_cvtss_f32` intrinsic:

```
float result = _mm_cvtss_f32(vector_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just worth pointing out taht if you're only using a single value, you ought to substitute ss intrinsics instead of ps where available; in this case, `_mm_store_ss` is perfectly valid for storing the low value to a single precision float without needing to use `_mm_cvtss_f32`.